# How can I add a new light fixture off of a ceiling fan wired to two switches?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, light-fixture

I have an existing ceiling fan rough in that is wired with 3 conductor wire to two switches, allowing the light and fan to be controlled independently.

The fan that I installed however uses a wireless controller for the fan and light control, and therefore only uses a single hot wire(one switch), the other conductor for the unused switch is just capped in the ceiling fan box.

I would like to add a separate ceiling light fixture in this room.  It has occurred to me that I have a switch that is not being used because the fan can only be controlled by a single switch.

Can I simply tap into the existing neutral, and unused hot in the ceiling fan to run to my new fixture?  This would save me from having to add a new switch.

In other words, I would run 14/2 from the ceiling fan fixture to the new light location.  I would tie the new hot to the unused hot in the ceiling fan fixture, tie neutral to neutral, and ground to ground.

This seems to be pretty straightforward, but I wanted to see if there was any reason this wouldn't be an acceptable approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So long as you will not overload the circuit (figure out what all is on the circuit), you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Completed this today and everything went smoothly.